# How to change color of row in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this part of code, but not working..

```
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg1.Rows)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now.Day;
            var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()).Day;

            if (now == expirationDate)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: WinForms I'm assuming.

Comment: You may need to post more than the code above. Hope You are not rebinding the Grid after this code snippet

Comment: I think the `if (now == expirationDate)` is the problem and that's why you cannot see the change of color. Try removing the `.Day` of both variables before comparing. Or simply remove the comparison first and see if there is a change on background color.

Comment: put your code in row or cell formatting event

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` not `.Day`

Answer (score 0):

Not good idea to compare classes/structs like that(with == operator)

try using

```
if(DateTime.Compare(now, expirationDate) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the comparison you're performing (as others are referring), but it would be better to compare `Date` using `DateTime.Compare` method.

The problem is you're not checking for `NewRow`. It causes exception when you try to read an empty `Row`.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg1.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `foreach` with `for`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dg1.Rows.Length; i++)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now.Day;
        var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(dg1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()).Day;

        if (now == expirationDate)
        {
            dg1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }
    }
```

The collection used in `foreach` is immutable.